# Can't login to asp.net web, Jmeter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jmeter

I am new in jmeter, I want to see performance when the user logs into my web. But when I see the results using ***'View Result Tree'*** and see ***'Response Data'*** and get this error. I developed using asp.net MVC

> The Anti-forgery token could not be decrypted.

screenshoot is below. Thanks :)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [authorization manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) for authentication.

Also, it seems header is missing in your request. Use [jmeter recording](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) to capture the requests and then perform the required correlation like anti-forgery token.

Hope this helps.